# Wordpress Custom Post Type link not showing content

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created 2 custom post types. One called artist and one called work. When I create a post in artist and view it the link is fine and I can view the content. However in work when I add a new post and go to view it it says that it cannot find the content and the page is missing.

Here is my functions.php code.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
register_post_type( 'artist',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Talent' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'talent' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'thumbnail' ),
    'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'talent'),

    )
);

register_post_type( 'work',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Content' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'content' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'supports' => array( 'thumbnail' ),
    'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'title', 'editor'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'content'),

    )
);
}
```

Comment: Flushed the permalinks?

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly!